# How to count Indic Script telugu Characters

Tags: javascript, count, character

I have some JavaScript that counts the total number of characters in a text box. It's fine with english, but when I type Telugu script it shows the wrong count. For example,

```
Anil = 4
అనిల్ = 4
```

But `అనిల్` is only three letters of Telugu script. How can I count indic script characters exactly?

Comment: Could you please supply the javascript that you are using?

Answer (score 5):

I don't know anything about Telugu, so the following might be completely wrong. Let me know.

`"అనిల్".split("")` prints `["అ", "న", "ి", "ల", "్"]` for me. The characters #2 and #4 appear to be combining marks rather than letters. We only want to count actual letters, so let's remove everything that isn't called a Telugu Letter in http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt and count the rest:

```
str = "అనిల్"
len = str.replace(/[^\u0C05-\u0C39\u0C58-\u0C61]/g, '').length
```

returns "3" as expected.

Comment: Yes. There are several ways to find the number of letters in the text. First one is to remove the combining marks as you suggested. Or, one can search for the pattern with [అ-ఔక-హ][diacriticmarks]* .  (my phone doesn't support the diacritic marks separately. Hence I cant write them within square brackets.)